# How to make pure, generic React components with immutable data that needs to be transformed

Tags: reactjs, redux

*Please also help me with the title and to express the problem better.*

I've met a problem in my react/redux architecture that I can't find many examples on.

My application relies on immutability, reference equality and `PureRenderMixin` for performance. But I find it hard to create more generic and reusable components with such architecture.

Lets say I have a generic `ListView` like this:

```js
const ListView = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        items: arrayOf(shape({
            icon: string.isRequired,
            title: string.isRequired,
            description: string.isRequired,
        })).isRequired,
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((item, idx) => (
                    <li key={idx}>
                        <img src={item.icon} />
                        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    },
});
```

And then I want to use the list view to display users from a redux store. They have this structure:

```js
const usersList = [
    { name: 'John Appleseed', age: 18, avatar: 'generic-user.png' },
    { name: 'Kate Example', age: 32, avatar: 'kate.png' },
];
```

This is a very normal senario in my applications so far. I usually render it like:

```js
<ListView items={usersList.map(user => ({
    title: user.name,
    icon: user.avatar,
    description: `Age: ${user.age}`,
}))} />
```

Problem is that `map` breaks the reference equality. The result of
`usersList.map(...)` will always be new list objects. So even when `usersList` hasn't changed since previous render, the `ListView` can't know that it still has a equal `items`-list.

I can see three solutions to this, but I don't like them very good.

**Solution 1: Pass a `transformItem`-function as a parameter and let `items` be an array of raw objects**

```js
const ListView = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        items: arrayOf(object).isRequired,
        transformItem: func,
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            transformItem: item => item,
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((item, idx) => {
                    const transformedItem = this.props.transformItem(item);

                    return (
                        <li key={idx}>
                            <img src={transformedItem.icon} />
                            <h3>{transformedItem.title}</h3>
                            <p>{transformedItem.description}</p>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    },
});
```

This will work very well. I can then render my user list like this:

```js
<ListView
    items={usersList}
    transformItem={user => ({
        title: user.name,
        icon: user.avatar,
        description: `Age: ${user.age}`,
    })}
/>
```

And the ListView will only rerender when `usersList` changes. But I lost the prop type validation on the way.

**Solution 2: Make a specialized component that wraps the `ListView`:**

```js
const UsersList = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        items: arrayOf(shape({
            name: string.isRequired,
            avatar: string.isRequired,
            age: number.isRequired,
        })),
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                items={this.props.items.map(user => ({
                    title: user.name,
                    icon: user.avatar,
                    description: user.age,
                }))}
            />
        );
    }
});
```

But that is a lot more code! Would be better if I could use a stateless component, but I haven't figured out if they works like normal components with `PureRenderMixin`. (stateless components is sadly still an undocumented feature of react)

```js
const UsersList = ({ users }) => (
    <ListView
        items={users.map(user => ({
            title: user.name,
            icon: user.avatar,
            description: user.age,
        }))}
    />
);
```

**Solution 3: Create a generic pure transforming component**

```js
const ParameterTransformer = React.createClass({
    mixin: [PureRenderMixin],

    propTypes: {
        component: object.isRequired,
        transformers: arrayOf(func).isRequired,
    },

    render() {
        let transformed = {};

        this.props.transformers.forEach((transformer, propName) => {
            transformed[propName] = transformer(this.props[propName]);
        });

        return (
            <this.props.component
                {...this.props}
                {...transformed}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </this.props.component>
        );
    }
});
```

and use it like

```js
<ParameterTransformer
    component={ListView}
    items={usersList}
    transformers={{
        items: user => ({
            title: user.name,
            icon: user.avatar,
            description: `Age: ${user.age}`,
        })
    }}
/>
```

**Are these the only solutions, or have I missed something?**

None of these solutions fits very well with the component I'm currently working on. Number one fits best, but I feel like if that is the track I choose to go on, then all kinds of generic components I make should have these `transform` properties. And also it is a major downside that I can't use React prop type validation when creating such components.

Solution 2 is probably the most semantic correct, at least for this `ListView` example. But I think it is very verbose, and also it doesn't fit very well with my real usecase.

Solution 3 is just too magic and unreadable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's another solution that's commonly used with Redux: **memoized selectors**.

Libraries like [Reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) provide a way to wrap a function (like your map call) in another function that checks the arguments for reference equality between calls, and returns a cached value if the arguments are unchanged.

Your scenario is a perfect example for a memoized selector—since you're enforcing immutability, you can make the assumption that as long as your `usersList` reference is the same, the output from your call to `map` will be the same. The selector can cache the return value of the `map` function until your `usersList` reference changes.

Using Reselect to create a memoized selector, you first need one (or more) input selectors, and a result function. The input selectors are generally used for selecting child items from a parent state object; in your case, you're selecting directly from the object you have, so you can pass the identity function as the first argument. The second argument, the result function, is the function that generates the value to be cached by the selector.

```
var createSelector = require('reselect').createSelector; // ES5
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'; // ES6

var usersListItemSelector = createSelector(
    ul => ul, // input selector
    ul => ul.map(user => { // result selector
        title: user.name,
        icon: user.avatar,
        description: `Age: ${user.age}`,
    })
);

// ...

<ListView items={usersListItemSelector(usersList)} />
```

Now, each time React renders your `ListView` component, your memoized selector will be called, and your `map` result function will only be called if a different `usersList` is passed in.

Comment: Memoization, yes, of course! How could I not think about that?

Or, the idea has stroke me, but I didn't think through it (have actually never needed memoization for anything useful before), so I thought it would result in a big cache of all previous selected lists. But of cource, no need to hold more than the most recent result and check against that.

Memoization is probably easier to implement myself instead of pulling in a library.

Comment: Sure, you could implement it yourself—Reselect is [only 82 lines of code](https://github.com/rackt/reselect/blob/master/src/index.js#L82).